# jQuery .load and WP function

Tags: jquery

I am attempting to get the [Quick Chat WordPress plugin](http://www.techytalk.info/quick-chat/) to load only if you click on a button.

I'm currently using this code:

```
$('#chat').load('path to my wp template/quick-chat.php');
```

... where the file 'quick-chat.php' has a WordPress function that calls Quick Chat. When the file loads, however, it's not recognizing the function. It's acting like it was outside of WordPress.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Your quick chat function is being loaded to late.  It needs to be loaded in the proper WordPress sequence by adding it through a plugin or in functions.php.